# Errors creating a new column of integers python and pandas

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I've followed some tutorials and advice here but struggling to get a new column I'm creating into integer format. The original code to create the new column here and it would be ideal to format the new column as integer when I create it - and I'm not sure why the new column is integer when I create it using integer values in the code?

Here's a truncated version of what I've done to create the new column

```py
data['avg_amout'] = [8000 if x == '$1,000 - $15,000' else 3000000 if x == '$1,000,001 - $5,000,000' else 750000 for x in data['amount']]
```

I've tried using `data['avg_amount'].astype(int)` in the code creating the column, I've also tried the two below lines to convert the column once it's been added to the dataframe, and I'm getting errors for all.

```py
data["avg_amount"] = pd.to_numeric(data["avg_amount"])
```

and

```py
pd.to_numeric(data['avg_amount'])
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample data?

Comment: Typo: `data['avg_amout']`

Comment: The column is being created as integer from my end. What is the problem?

Comment: It's being created as a string on my end and I can't perform and calculations on the data? Indeed it was a typo, and after correcting that I can successfully run:
    data["average_amount"] = pd.to_numeric(data["avg_amount"])
but still showing as a str for me?

Comment: So the output of ```data['avg_amount'].dtype``` is an object?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I restarted the kernal and all appears to be working now